# Bind a method with time-out event in TestNG

Tags: testng

In a TestNG project, I added a time-out in suite tag in xml file.

```
<suite name="Acceptance test suite" verbose="1" time-out="5400000" parallel="instances" thread-count="15">
```

This timeout is working fine.

I want to bind a method that will execute whenever an individual test will timeout. Actually, I want to log that this specific test is terminated by `TestNG` framework and couple of other tasks by using the information of test that just terminated.

I have checked the Annotation `@AfterTest` but it execute when all tests are completed. I want to log at individual test level.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it with TestNG as of today. You just need to extract out the `Throwable` object from the `ITestResult` of a particular test method, check if it is a timeout exception and if yes, log it separately.

As of today there's no straight forward way of doing this via a TestNG listener. I have logged a new issue for tracking this (https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1952) I will try and get to fixing this at the earliest and have it available in the next upcoming major release of TestNG. Please feel free to watch this issue for updates.

Here's a sample that shows how to do it.

```java
import com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn53280681.TimeoutListener;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.testng.ITestListener;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.annotations.Listeners;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.internal.thread.ThreadTimeoutException;

@Listeners(TimeoutListener.class)
public class qn53280681 {
  @Test(timeOut = 500)
  public void timedMethod() throws InterruptedException {
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
  }

  public static class TimeoutListener implements ITestListener {

    @Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
      Throwable t = result.getThrowable();
      if (t instanceof ThreadTimeoutException) {
        System.err.println("The test timedout and caused a failure");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here's the output

```
The test timedout and caused a failure

org.testng.internal.thread.ThreadTimeoutException: Method com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn53280681.timedMethod() didn't finish within the time-out 500

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1150)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


===============================================
Default Suite
Total tests run: 1, Passes: 0, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================
```